# Web GIS application for ArcGIS users

Tags: gis, arcgis, arcgis-js-api, arcgis-server

Can I create a ArcGIS web application without *ArcGIS server*, using only **ArcGIS online services**?

Comment: If you have more questions along these lines, you might find even more people who want to help over at http://gis.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 4):

**Yes.**

The only thing that ArcGIS server would be supplying to a web application is map services or geoprocessing services. These can be hosted on ArcGIS Online (AGOL) instead. For examples, look at the [ArcGIS JavaScript API samples](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jssamples/), almost all of which use AGOL map services in their implementation.

The application itself, if built in JavaScript, can be hosted on any web server and does not require an ArcGIS Server install.

Comment: Thanks Erica, that's helpful

Answer (score 4):

Absolutely! You can easily upload your data to ArcGIS Online and [create Hosted Feature Services](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/share-maps/publish-features.htm), then [add those to a web map](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/create-maps/create-maps-and-apps.htm), and then [create an app based on that web map](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/create-maps/choose-configurable-app.htm) (no coding is even required unless you need something customized for your workflow). Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for lucid explanation

Comment: I also encourage you to [sign-up for a developer account](https://developers.arcgis.com/sign-up/) in case you don't have one, and if you are not very familiar with ArcGIS Desktop I would [create a hosted feature service using the developer console](https://developers.arcgis.com/layers/#/new/).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, although currently MapServer service is not listed under supported types of *hosted* layers:

https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/share-maps/hosted-web-layers.htm

MapServer allows for delivering just map images for an individual service to the client and provides the feature data by request. Hosting it doesn't seem to be a option in ArcGIS Online in current implementation.